# Protocol delegate doesn't call

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in Swift UIKit and tried to make application with VIPER architecture. I was trying to make it according to [this topic](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-implement-viper-architecture-in-your-ios-app-rest-api-and-kingfisher-f494a0891c43), but I can't call presenter function from view. Here is my ViewController code

```
class PokemonViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupUI()
    
    presenter?.viewDidLoad()
}

@objc func refresh() {
    presenter?.refresh()
}

var presenter: ViewToPresenterPokemonsProtocol?

let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout.init())
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    return collectionView
}()

lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Refreshing")
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
    return refreshControl
}()

}

extension PokemonViewController: PresenterToViewPokemonsProtocol {

func onFetchPokemonsSuccess() {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

func onFetchPokemonsFailure(error: String) {
    print("View receives the response from Presenter with error: \(error)")
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
}
```

And my presenter code

```
class PokemonPresenter : ViewToPresenterPokemonsProtocol {

weak var view: PresenterToViewPokemonsProtocol?
var interactor: PresenterToInteractorPokemonsProtocol?
var router: PresenterToRouterPokemonsProtocol?

var pokemons: [Pokemon]?

func viewDidLoad() {
    print("Presenter is being notified that View was loaded.")
    interactor?.loadPokemons()
}

func refresh() {
    print("Presenter is being notified that the View was refreshed.")
    interactor?.loadPokemons()
}
}

extension PokemonPresenter: InteractorToPresenterPokemonsProtocol {
func fetchPokemonsSuccess(pokemons: [Pokemon]) {
    print("Presenter receives the result from Interactor after it's done its job.")
    self.pokemons = pokemons
    view?.onFetchPokemonsSuccess()
}

func fetchPokemonsFailure(error: String) {
    print("Presenter receives the result from Interactor after it's done its job.")
    view?.onFetchPokemonsFailure(error: "Couldn't fetch pokemons: \(error)")
}

//    func getPokemonSuccess(_ pokemon: Pokemon) {
//        router?.pushToPokemonDetail(on: view!, with: pokemon)
//    }

func getPokemonFailure() {
    print("Couldn't retrieve pokemon by index")
}
}
```

So I don't know what am I doing wrong when I'm calling presenter's viewDidLoad. my breakpoints triggers when view calling presenter's viewDidLoad but breakpoint in preset's viewDidLoad doesn't trigger.

Comment: `presenter's viewDidLoad but breakpoint in preset's viewDidLoad doesn't trigger.` check if the `presenter` is nil or not. Where should it be set? Where the code that's setting it?

Comment: What viper architecture are you using?

Comment: @matt https://github.com/zafarivaev/VIPER-Demo-App here is the code of this architecture and here https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-implement-viper-architecture-in-your-ios-app-rest-api-and-kingfisher-f494a0891c43 is the topic

Comment: OK, fine. Notice the `createModule` method of the QuotesRouter class in that project. It hooks the module together, creating the presenter and assigning it into the view controller `presenter` property etc. It looks like you forgot that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have two different PokemonViewController instances in your app - the one that you create in the module router, and the one that comes from the storyboard.

Why? You are using a scene delegate. Therefore, that is where the window is, and that is where the storyboard gets loaded automatically. You need to prevent that and construct the interface by hand — in the scene delegate, not in the app delegate. The app delegate code is useless; it assembles a hierarchy including the viper module, but all of that gets thrown away, because the app delegate's `window` is not part of the interface.

The solution is:

- Edit the Info.plist. In the Application Scene Manifest, drill down to the Storyboard Name and delete it.
- Rewrite the first method of the scene delegate so that it does the work your app delegate was doing.

Like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
    window?.backgroundColor = .white
    window?.rootViewController = PokemonRouter.createModule()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to figure this out. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my problem!! I could spend much more time on solving it without you :)